# Using JsonObjectRequest inside JsonArrayRequest

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

Newbie here, i'm working on a simple app that display list of place based on api data for my assignment.

I'm planning to make a simple recyclerview that display preview image, place name, and place rating.

Here is the json that contain array of object

```
[
   {
      "xid":"N2180835380",
      "name":"Stasiun Waytuba",
      "rate":3,
      "osm":"node/2180835380",
      "wikidata":"Q19741325",
      "kinds":"industrial_facilities,railway_stations,interesting_places",
      "point":{
         "lon":104.411728,
         "lat":-4.379512
      }
   },
   {
      "xid":"N5374585862",
      "name":"Stasiun Martapura",
      "rate":3,
      "osm":"node/5374585862",
      "wikidata":"Q19741099",
      "kinds":"other,unclassified_objects,interesting_places,tourist_object",
      "point":{
         "lon":104.346565,
         "lat":-4.316566
      }
   },
   {
      ...
   }
]
```

But, the image url doesn't exist on that json instead it exist on another json which is the detail of specific item.

```
{
   "xid":"N2180835380",
   "name":"Stasiun Waytuba",
   "address":{
      "state":"Lampung",
      "country":"Indonesia",
      "village":"Way Tuba",
      "postcode":"34767",
      "country_code":"id"
   },
   "rate":"3",
   "osm":"node/2180835380",
   "wikidata":"Q19741325",
   "kinds":"industrial_facilities,railway_stations,interesting_places",
   "sources":{
      "geometry":"osm",
      "attributes":[
         "osm",
         "wikidata"
      ]
   },
   "otm":"https://opentripmap.com/en/card/N2180835380",
   "wikipedia":"https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stasiun%20Way%20Tuba",
   "image":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stasiun_Waytuba_08-2015.jpg",
   "preview":{
      "source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Stasiun_Waytuba_08-2015.jpg/400px-Stasiun_Waytuba_08-2015.jpg",
      "height":293,
      "width":400
   },
   "wikipedia_extracts":{
      "title":"id:Stasiun Way Tuba",
      "text":"Stasiun Way Tuba (WAY) adalah stasiun kereta api kelas II yang berada di Way Tuba, Way Tuba, Way Kanan. Stasiun yang terletak pada ketinggian +81 meter ini termasuk ke dalam Divisi Regional IV Tanjungkarang. Stasiun ini mempunyai 2 jalur rel dengan jalur 2 merupakan sepur lurus.Semua perjalanan kereta api yang melayani rute Kertapati–Tanjungkarang pasti berhenti di stasiun ini.",
      "html":"<p><b>Stasiun Way Tuba</b> (<b>WAY</b>) adalah stasiun kereta api kelas II yang berada di Way Tuba, Way Tuba, Way Kanan. Stasiun yang terletak pada ketinggian +81 meter ini termasuk ke dalam Divisi Regional IV Tanjungkarang. Stasiun ini mempunyai 2 jalur rel dengan jalur 2 merupakan sepur lurus.</p><p>Semua perjalanan kereta api yang melayani rute Kertapati–Tanjungkarang pasti berhenti di stasiun ini.</p>"
   },
   "point":{
      "lon":104.411728,
      "lat":-4.379512
   }
}
```

That was a json data that contain the detail of place on the first list.

Here is my code, for now i just display the list only with name and rating, since i don't know how to fetch image url inside the JsonArrayRequest.

```
package com.example.explorev10;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlaceListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private PlaceAdapter mPlaceAdapter;
    private ArrayList<PlaceItem> mPlaceList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_list);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_place_list);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parseJSON();
    }

    private void parseJSON() {
        String jsonURL = "https://api.opentripmap.com/0.1/en/places/bbox?lon_min=104.268781&lat_min=-5.780249&lon_max=105.755215&lat_max=-4.101807&kinds=interesting_places&format=json&apikey=5ae2e3f221c38a28845f05b65ba166329393551235361ab9b66e2889";

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, jsonURL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject place = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                String placeName = place.getString("name");
                                int placeRating = place.getInt("rate");
                                String imageURL = "";

                                mPlaceList.add(new PlaceItem(imageURL, placeName, placeRating));
                            }

                            mPlaceAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(PlaceListActivity.this, mPlaceList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPlaceAdapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

How can i access the place detail as JsonObject inside the for loop?
Can someone help me please?? Thank you so much ..
Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0):

Along with name and rate store xid in Places pojo class and call second api in response listener of first api instead of calling recycler view, once second api response is completed pass the list to recycler view

```
 private void parseSecondJSON() {
    
    String jsonURL = "secondurl";
    
    
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, jsonURL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < mPlaceList.size(); i++) {
                        
                            if(mPlaceList.get(i).xid.equals(response.xid)) {
                                
                                mPlaceList.get(i).image = response.image;
                        
                            }
                        
                        }

                        mPlaceAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(PlaceListActivity.this, mPlaceList);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPlaceAdapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to tell you before, json that contain the detail differ for each place based on their xid. For example

http://api.opentripmap.com/0.1/en/places/xid/N2180835380?apikey=5ae2e3f221c38a28845f05b65ba166329393551235361ab9b66e2889

and

http://api.opentripmap.com/0.1/en/places/xid/N5374585862?apikey=5ae2e3f221c38a28845f05b65ba166329393551235361ab9b66e2889

So each detail was only for one item place. Do you have any solution?